# How to tap a button with one touch, when keyboard is open (instead of 2)

Tags: android, keyboard, focus

I have the keyboard open in my app, I want the user to be able to type, and then tap a colour selector widget I have made (which changes text colour). The problem is that it takes 2 taps, the first one closes the keyboard, the second one actually selects my colour picker. Is there a way to make this one tap? and also keep the keyboard open if possible, so they can change colour then go back to typing without focus issues.

Comment: Please provide the code where you are handling the `onTouch` event.

Comment: It is handled by the system, let's forget the colour picker for now, since I also have a normal button for when you are finished editing the text. This button also requires 2 taps (one to get rid of keyboard, one to tap it). The button is simply using an OnClickListener right now.

Comment: this turned out to be my own invisible view blocking keypresses, so my own fault.